# convert image with (.raw) format to (.jpg) format in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

This is my code:

```
f=fopen('m-001-1.raw');
a=fread(f);
input_img = reshape(a,768, 576, 3);
input_img = imrotate(input_img, -90);
imwrite(input_img, 'm-001-1.jpg');
```

but it doesn't save image as `.jpg` format, how could I improve it?

Comment: So what is it saving as? What does `imshow(input_img)` display?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect answer, but too long for a comment. However it is probably the "solution"

Its probably writing an  image and you are not seeing what you want, rigth? The problem with "RAW" format is that it is not a format itself, its literally raw data from the camera. It seems that you know the shape of your data , guessing by your "`reshape(a,768, 576, 3);`", but do you know its amplitude?

Usually in raw you will have binary numbers, you need to convert them to your amplitude.

Say, your camera is a 14 bit per pixel camera, then you need to scale the binary numbers you get accordingly. You'll need to scale them to 8 bits (or something else, but something matlab can handle )for saving and displaying.

Even more, sometimes raw data is not even stored linearly! (look [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/03/08/tips-for-reading-a-camera-raw-file-into-matlab/) for tips of reading raw data) so you may be getting wrong images. [Or maybe the las 4 bits are some kind of encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format#Processing)! [There are different ways of reading and storing RGB images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_filter_array)!

All this information is hardware specific, so there is no way we can help you, as we dont know your hardware.

So in short. You need LOTS of more information for reading and dealing with raw data, and its information YOU have, and we dont. Maybe if you tell us which hardware you used for the raw data we can help, but usually is a too tedious work and probably nobody will use half of his/her day in that for you.

Cheers.

PD: some interesting links

Matlab file exchange

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23394-fast-import-of-compressed-binary-raw-files-created-with-ltspice-circuit-simulator

Matlab file exchange

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29344-read-medical-data-3d

**Matlab file exchange**

[**http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7412-raw-camera-file-reader**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7412-raw-camera-file-reader)

PDF wit tips

http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~rcsumner/rawguide/RAWguide.pdf